# GET request JSONObject android

Tags: android, json, http, get, connection

i did a simple GET request, who return 1 or 0 if my login & password are correct.
I do my connection on an other thread .

Like this :

```
public void getConnection(){

    String url = null;

    url = NOM_HOTE + PATH_METHODE + "identifiant="+ identifiant.getText().toString() + "&password="+ password.getText().toString();

     HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

     try{
         HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
         HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
         HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

         if(httpEntity != null){


             InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

             //Lecture du retour au format JSON
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
             StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

             String ligneLue = bufferedReader.readLine();
             while(ligneLue != null){
                 stringBuilder.append(ligneLue + " \n");
                 ligneLue = bufferedReader.readLine();
             }
             bufferedReader.close();

             JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

             Log.i("Chaine JSON", stringBuilder.toString());   


             JSONObject jsonResultSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("nb"); <--it's here where the error occured

//               int nombreDeResultatsTotal = jsonResultSet.getInt("nb");
//               Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Resultats retourne" + nombreDeResultatsTotal);    

         }// <-- end IF          
     }catch (IOException e){
         Log.e(LOG_TAG+ "1", e.getMessage());
     }catch (JSONException e){
         Log.e(LOG_TAG+ "2", e.getMessage());

     }
}
```

i have a JSON return like this : `{"nb":"1"}` or `{"nb":"0"}`
So my JSON is correct. but i have this error on `catch(JSONException`) when i submit my form :

**11-07 17:01:57.833: E/ClientJSON2(32530): Value 1 at nb of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**

i don't understand why , whereas my syntax, connection  are correct and on the Log with tag "Chaine JSON" , i have `{"nb:"1"}` in the response..

Answer (score 5):

nb is a `String`, not a `JSONObject`. Change

```
JSONObject jsonResultSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("nb");
```

in

```
String result = jsonObject.getString("nb");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String myReturnValue = jsonObject. getString("nb");
```

instead of

```
JSONObject jsonResultSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject("nb");
```

This will return you a String ;)

Comment: change `jsonObject.getJSONString("nb")` to `jsonObject.getInt("nb")` because getJSONString is not method of JSONObject class

Comment: Thank i try it and i will say you where i 'am :)

Comment: Also, it should be `getString`, not `getJSONString`

Comment: Yes it's work ! and brianestey ,It's beautiful is getString() =)         thank everybody :)

Answer (score 0):

value represented by "nb" is a string not object.

use `jsonObject.getString("nb");` even `jsonObject.getInt("nb");` would work if value is a numerical